# WPF MVVM Light storyboard errors

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mvvm-light, ribbon-control

I keep getting this message and I am using a ribbon bar in my WPF MVVM-Light application, and I would like to get rid of it.

```
 System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; 
Action='Stop'; 
Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; 
Storyboard.HashCode='21044390'; 
Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; 
TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; 
TargetElement.HashCode='21044390'; 
TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'
```

I don't see any storyboard stuff or references to it in my ribbon bar, and it's a lot of code to post.  Let me know if you think I should.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  That answer involved actually calling code to access animations.  I am not using any animation and simply want to get rid of the error.