# WPF Ribbon Storyboard Error

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I have created a bare-bones WPF application with only a ribbon in the window:

```
<RibbonWindow  [[Usual XMLNS tags]]>
<Grid>
    <Ribbon SelectedIndex="0"  >
        <RibbonTab Header="First" KeyTip="H">
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="First" Header="First">
                <RibbonMenuItem Header="Open"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="Second" Header="Second">
                <RibbonMenuItem Header="Save"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
</Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

The ribbon displays exactly as expected.  When I hover the mouse over either the Open or Save buttons, the button highlights, again as expected, but I get the following warning:

```
System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : 
Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; 
Action='Stop'; 
Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
Storyboard.HashCode='31656086';
Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
TargetElement.HashCode='31656086';
TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'
```

Again, this is a bare-bones application. I have not created any storyboards.  I did a global solution search for both "Stop" and "Storyboard" to ensure that there wasn't something in the autogenerated files, but I couldn't find either keyword.

Any suggestions?  The Ribbon seems to behave exactly as expected.  However, I hate starting a project with a warning.  This question IS a duplicate of  previously asked question [25866393](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866393/wpf-mvvm-light-storyboard-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1).  However THAT question was closed as a duplicate of [12981771](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981771/wpf-animation-warning-6-unable-to-perform-action), even though 12981771 does not answer the question at all.

It is clear from other questions that this error gets triggered when an animation's `Stop()` method is called without calling the `Begin()` method.  But in my case I don't have any animations or storyboards that I have declared - so I don't know when `Stop()` or `Begin()` might be getting called, or by who.  I confirmed that both the application and window `Resources` collections are empty.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Was it solved? How?

Comment: @Patrick - Nope never got a resolution to this.  I just learned to live with it, even though I hate getting unexplained errors in a bare bones application